# Converting to UTF-8 (again)

Tags: python, utf-8, character-encoding

I've this string `Traor\u0102\u0160`

`Traor\u0102\u0160` Should produce `TraorÃ©`. Then `TraorÃ©` utf-8 decoded should produce `Traorè`

How I can convert it to `Traorè` ?

What kind of chars are `Traor\u0102\u0160`? Unicode?

I've already read this http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html#encodings many times. But I'm still really confused.

I get this data with the following request:

```
import json
import requests

# making a request to get this json
r = requests.get('http://cdn.content.easports.com/fifa/fltOnlineAssets/2013/fut/items/web/199074.json')
print r.json
```

### Solution

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import json
import requests

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

r = requests.get('http://cdn.content.easports.com/fifa/fltOnlineAssets/2013/fut/items/web/199074.json', headers=headers)


print r.content

#prints
{"Item":{"FirstName":"Lacina","LastName":"Traoré","CommonName":null,"Height":"203","DateOfBirth":{"Year":"1990","Month":"8","Day":"20"},"PreferredFoot":"Left","ClubId":"100766","LeagueId":"67","NationId":"108","Rating":"78","Attribute1":"79","Attribute2":"71","Attribute3":"45","Attribute4":"69","Attribute5":"50","Attribute6":"72","Rare":"1","ItemType":"PlayerA"}}
```

Basically I needed to set to send the rigth headers.

Thank you all

Comment: How did you get that string? It looks like you've double-encoded, because those are two unicode characters, neither of which is an e with grave accent.

Comment: Indeed. You need to fix the step which produced `Traor\u0102\u0160`. It should instead have produced `Traor\u00E8`.

Comment: Traor\u0102\u0160 Should produce TraorÃ©. Then TraorÃ© utf-8 decoded should produce Traorè

Comment: No, it stands for `TraorĂŠ`. It are just unicode escape sequences. As said, you need to go one step back in your process. It should in first place not have given you `Traor\u0102\u0160` at all. It should have given you `Traor\u00E8` which stands for `Traorè`.

Comment: It *could* also be `e\u0300`; an e with a combining accent grave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me your site returns `"Traor\u00e9"` ([the last character is `é`](http://codepoints.net/U+00E9)):

```
r = requests.get(url)
print(json.dumps(json.loads(r.content)['Item']['LastName']))
# -> "Traor\u00e9" -> Traoré
```

`r.json` (`r.text`) produces incorrect content here. Either server or `requests` or both use incorrect encoding that results in `"Traor\u0102\u0160"`. The encoding of JSON text is completely defined by its content therefore it is always possible to decode it whatever headers server sends, from [json rfc](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627):

> JSON text SHALL be encoded in Unicode.  The default encoding is
> UTF-8.
>
> Since the first two characters of a JSON text will always be ASCII
> characters [RFC0020], it is possible to determine whether an octet
> stream is UTF-8, UTF-16 (BE or LE), or UTF-32 (BE or LE) by looking
> at the pattern of nulls in the first four octets.

```
       00 00 00 xx  UTF-32BE
       00 xx 00 xx  UTF-16BE
       xx 00 00 00  UTF-32LE
       xx 00 xx 00  UTF-16LE
       xx xx xx xx  UTF-8
```

In this case there are no zero bytes at the start of `r.content` so `json.loads` works otherwise you need manually to convert it to a Unicode string if the server sends incorrect character encoding in `Content-Type` header or to workaround `requests` bug

Comment: Interesting. The JSON encoding is certainly incorrect in that the standard states it should return `\u00e9`. Didn't occur to me to blame `requests` here (or HTTPie for that matter). The *raw* data contains `"Traor\xc3\xa9"` which is quite wrong.

Comment: Ah! `json.loads(r.content)['Item']['LastName']` returns `u'Traor\xe9'` which is indeed `Traoré`. That means `json.loads` takes into account that the data could be UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: It is not necessary to encode `é` as `\u00e9` inside json string.

Comment: The headers don't include an encoding, so this is a `requests` bug.

Comment: The last thing, what's the fastest way to convert "Traor\u00e9" to "Traorè" ?

Comment: @gaggina: it already *is* that string. You need to read up on Unicode, I fear, at [this excellent article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html). If you need to reproduce it on a screen or in a GUI, you need to encode it to an appropriate encoding using the `.encode()` method, *perhaps*. Many output methods do the encoding for you, for example.

Comment: @gaggina: as for the bug in `requests`, the code is indeed using `chardet` to detect the encoding and that guesses wrong. It should not try and guess the encoding at all like that. In this case the guess is `ISO-8859-2`, which is perfectly consistent with the end result, but very wrong.

Comment: An issue on this was previously closed: https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/765. I've responded.

Comment: @gaggina: I've used `json.dumps()` to convert the python Unicode string to a JSON string represented in ASCII to avoid possible problems with printing Unicode to your console that can be a big issue on Windows by itself.

Comment: @gaggina: I've submitted a [patch for `requests`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/pull/909) that would fix this for you, removing the need to explicitly set `r.encoding` to `UTF-8`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Is it valid to decode body using other than UTF-8 encoding for application/json content-type if charset is not specified? Or do you want to introduce some more magic to `requests` to accept even invalid input?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: The JSON RFC does not specify that a content-type header is required when transmitting JSON, let alone that it should specify an encoding at all. Although the HTTP RFCs does require a `charset` to be set (with a default of latin-1 for `text/*` mimetypes), it also acknowledges that when missing the recipient will have to guess. Back to the JSON RFC then, and that basically gives you the tools to determine the encoding reliably. So, yes, it's valid to make such a guess (which in the case of a valid RFC-compliant JSON body is not a guess at all).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Note that my patch only introduces the UTF guess when you request a JSON decode and there is no encoding set. In that case, assuming there is a valid JSON body, we can determine the UTF encoding used. If we *fail* in that determination (no BOM, wrong null count or not in the right places), it falls back to the old guess-the-characterset method already used. If the decode failed, then obviously the input was invalid, and we fall back to the old method as well. So, in the end, it works correctly for valid RFC-compliant JSON and may fail if it is violating the RFC somehow.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: 1. Unless content-type is application/json (or derivative); json rfc doesn't apply at all so it is natural that it doesn't talk about it 2. json rfc explicitly specifies default encoding UTF-8, no guessing is required. 3. The fact that you can assert that utf-* encoding is correct is a bonus (to check whether the server misbehaves). There is no requirement to detect the encoding that way. Whether some standard forbids applying such detection instead of using utf-8  was my initial question.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Sure, the default is `UTF8`, but no mechanism to communicate derivation from the default is discussed in the RFC. All we *do* have is section 3, which enigmatically discusses detecting what UTF encoding is used for an octet stream. So sending a JSON response using UTF-16 over HTTP without a charset entry is perfectly valid, the JSON RFC doesn't prohibit it, neither the HTTP RFC. Since no charset is set, we do have to guess, and the nature of JSON let's us do so.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: As far as `requests` is concerned, the library does not enforce the `application/json` mimetype when accessing the `.json` property. And even if the proper interpretation to RFC were to be that JSON must be UTF8 when the encoding is absent from the response, verifying the UTF encoding rather than hardcode it *or* using `chardet` guessing would be a vast improvement over the current situation, *and* allow for more flexibility where we can be 100% certain another UTF encoding was used. The right thing for the server to do is of course to set the `charset` attribute.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: last but not least: if it is RFC compliant JSON we are dealing with, it's a determination of the encoding, not a guess. In all other cases we are well outside of the RFCs, so guessing is certainly allowed to try and make things work anyway. The web has always worked like that; be tolerant of failure. I believe even the HTTP spec encourages that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I've posted [related issue as a separate question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13096259/4279)

Answer (score 7):

You need tell requests what [encoding to expect](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-content):

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get(url)
>>> r.encoding = 'UTF-8'
>>> r.json[u'Item'][u'LastName']
u'Traor\xe9'
```

Otherwise, you'll get this:

```
>>> r = requests.get(url)
>>> r.json['Item']['LastName']
u'Traor\u0102\u0160'
```

Comment: Still a bug in requests; chardet is the wrong tool for the job there.

Comment: I'm not sure I would characterize it as a bug, it is documented at least. _"When you make a request, Requests makes educated guesses about the encoding of the response based on the HTTP headers."_; but I agree that they should avoid guessing and be explicit about it.

Comment: Also, I just checked the headers that the server sends; and after seeing the _typos in the headers_ I would point the finger at the server and not requests.

Comment: But it is a bug, because JSON content is always a UTF-style encoding. The RFC even tells you how to decode it properly. Yes, there are typos, but not in the Content-Type header, and the JSON RFC is quite clear the default should be UTF-8.

Comment: I'm responding to a previously closed issue in the `requests` tracker: https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/765

Answer (score 4):

You have run into a bug in `requests`; when the server does not set an explicit encoding, `requests` uses [`chardet`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) to make an educated guess about the encoding.

In this particular case, it gets that wrong; `chardet` thinks it's `ISO-8859-2` instead of `UTF-8`. The issue has been reported to the maintainers of `requests` as [issue 765](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/765).

The maintainers closed that issue, blaming the problem on the server not setting a character encoding for the response. The work-around is to set `r.encoding = 'utf-8'` before accessing `r.json` so that the contents are correctly decoded without guessing.

However, as [J.F. Sebastian correctly points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13069037/100297), if the response really *is* JSON, then the encoding has to be one of the UTF family of encodings. The [JSON RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627#section-3) even includes a section on how to detect what encoding was used.

I've submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/pull/909) to the `requests` project that does just that; if you ask for the JSON decoded response, and no encoding has been set, it'll detect the correct UTF encoding used instead of guessing.

With this patch in place, the URL loads without setting the encoding explicitly:

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('http://cdn.content.easports.com/fifa/fltOnlineAssets/2013/fut/items/web/199074.json')
>>> r.json[u'Item'][u'LastName']
u'Traor\xe9'
>>> print r.json[u'Item'][u'LastName']
Traoré
```