# Can charset parameter be used with application/json content type in http/1.1?

Tags: json, http, character-encoding

[For example, is it valid ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26620):

```javascript
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "SomePage.aspx/GetSomeObjects",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    ...
});
```

It is [used as an example sometimes](http://pyramid.readthedocs.org/en/latest/narr/webob.html#request-json-body), or software [can break without explicit charset](http://bugs.cometd.org/browse/COMETD-55).

[The rfc 4627 for application/json media type](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627#section-6) says that it doesn't accept any parameters in section 6:

```
The MIME media type for JSON text is application/json.

Type name: application

Subtype name: json

Required parameters: n/a

Optional parameters: n/a
```

[It can be interpreted that charset shouldn't be used with application/json](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/issues/454).

And [section 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627#section-3) suggests
that it is not necessary to specify charset:

```
JSON text SHALL be encoded in Unicode.  The default encoding is
UTF-8.

Since the first two characters of a JSON text will always be ASCII
characters [RFC0020], it is possible to determine whether an octet
stream is UTF-8, UTF-16 (BE or LE), or UTF-32 (BE or LE) by looking
at the pattern of nulls in the first four octets.

        00 00 00 xx  UTF-32BE
        00 xx 00 xx  UTF-16BE
        xx 00 00 00  UTF-32LE
        xx 00 xx 00  UTF-16LE
        xx xx xx xx  UTF-8
```

because UTF-8,16,32 encodings can be infered from the content. Why does it say that UTF-8 is default? The way to choose other character encoding is not specified in the rfc and the encoding can be found deterministically anyway. Or are there other (not UTF-8,16,32) character encodings that support Unicode?

Some argue that [charset can be used](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=915):

> I disagree with your assessment that it *must* be dropped.  RFC 2046
> states that "other media types than subtypes of "text" might choose to
> employ the charset parameter as defined here," which indicates that
> there is no restriction on the presence of the charset parameter on
> application types.  Additionally, RFC 2045 states that "MIME
> implementations must ignore any parameters whose names they do not
> recognize."  So, it is not reasonable to assume that there is any harm
> being done by its presence.

May rfc-compliant software generate content type application/json with a charset parameter? Should rfc-compliant software accept such requests?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The recent [json rfc 7159 says](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#page-11):

> Note:  No "charset" parameter is defined for this registration.
> Adding one really has no effect on compliant recipients.

i.e., `charset` must be ignored by compliant recipients.

It is consistent with rfc 2045: *"MIME implementations must ignore any parameters whose names they do not recognize."* because rfc 7159 still specifies: *"Required parameters:  n/a; Optional parameters:  n/a"* for application/json mime media type (no parameters).

The json text is no longer constrained to be an object or an array and the [old section 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627#section-3) that computes the character encoding based on the first two characters is gone in the new rfc.  UTF-8, UTF-16, or UTF-32 are allowed but there is no way to specify the encoding (no BOM, UTF-8 is the default).

> Can charset parameter be used with application/json content type in http/1.1?

There is no harm if `charset="utf-8"` is used -- utf-8 is the default encoding for json text but other values might be misleading because the value must be ignored by compliant recipients. It can only break clients that parse Content-Type header incorrectly e.g., [by comparing it verbatim with "application/json"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13096259/can-charset-parameter-be-used-with-application-json-content-type-in-http-1-1#comment17837630_13098683) or clients that attempt to use some other than utf-8 encoding to decode the json text.

> May rfc-compliant software generate content type application/json with a charset parameter?

no. No parameters are defined for application/json.

> Should rfc-compliant software accept such requests?

yes, it should. The value of `charset` must be ignored.

---

ECMA-404 (The JSON Data Interchange Format) defines json text in terms of Unicode code points i.e., json itself specifies no behavior regarding encoding details.

ECMA-262 (ECMAScript Language Specification) also defines the json format on top of String (Unicode type).

Answer (score 8):

application/json doesn't define a charset parameter, so it is incorrect to include one. What RFC 2046 says is that application types in general *could* have a charset parameter, such as application/xml. But JSON does not.

Comment: What about the quote from rfc 2045? Sending appropriate charset must be safe.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: You're here assuming that the implementation you're talking to implements all the relevant standards exactly to the letter. That's a pretty big assumption. Usually what one wants is "what is (a) arguably not wrong _and_ (b) least likely to create interoperability problems with implementations that _are_ slightly wrong?"

Comment: @Henning: no. I don't assume it (you can see non-confirming examples in my question and in some of the links in it). And I agree on both (a) and (b). Can you provide a non-hypotetical example where sending appropriate charset breaks a slightly wrong implementation?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: For example the slightly wrong application may be doing something like:
     `if( httpHeader.getHeaderLineContent("Content-Type").trim().equals("application/json") ) { ... }`
to decide whether to parse the input as JSON. If you think it doesn't, then you **are** assuming that the implementation you're talking to implements all the relevant standards exactly to the letter.

Comment: Unfortunately [this bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=438464&) in Chrome and a similar one in Firefox are making developers add `; charset=utf-8`... So don't worry it won't be long until it gets added to the spec that it's ok to do that  :)

Comment: @StijndeWitt - no, it won't get added to the spec just because Chrome is broken.

Comment: @JulianReschke No. But not only Chrome is broken, also Firefox. So together half of the browser market is broken atm. As a result, thousands of devs are changing their software because they value *working* software higher than *compliant* software. As a result, we will see `; charset=utf-8` being appended for years to come in many software packages. And as a result of that, pragmatic standards designers *should* just amend the spec to allow this... And I'm guessing they will eventually. And yes, I too changed my software to get it *working* i.s.o spec-compliant.

Comment: @StijndeWitt - I wasn't aware that Firefox is broken as well (-> https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=741776); but no, that doesn't mean the specification will be changed.

Comment: @JulianReschke Thanks for finding that bug report! I had searched but could not find it. And well, I just *hope* that they will do the pragmatic thing and just update the spec to fit the real world instead of making us choose between two evils. Same goes for use of the BOM marker in JSON streams which should also be allowed imho.

Comment: @StijndeWitt Very unlikely; you may want to head over to the IETF JSONBIS Working Group: https://datatracker.ietf.org/wg/jsonbis/charter/

Answer (score 0):

> Should rfc-compliant software accept such requests?

According to Julian Reschke's answer, apparently not. However, as you pointed out, **you will potentially encounter it in the wild and then would have to cope with it**, if you want to talk to those non-rfc compliant hosts.

For one, if you have code in place that handles `Accept-Charset` and the charset part of content types for text-based messages in your HTTP framework, why not just use it for JSON, too? Programming-wise, it is both easier (no special rule for json) and more general.

Personally, I'd say let's go Unicode (using the encoding detection you quote) for every bit of text. Unfortunately, there are client **devices** out there, e.g. Japanese mobile phones, **that don't handle Unicode**, but only `Shift_JIS`. They'd otherwise be happy JSON consumers (and paying customers). So what are you going to do? In my particular case, to get these clients on board, I made the charset configurable via the standard HTTP mechanisms.

On a side note, `HTTP 2.0` is being worked on right now, and if the guys ever hope to create a standard that is rigidly adhered to, they will have to write acceptance tests. That could of course also mean excluding aforementioned legacy clients if the rules can't be bent occasionally.

And what's the point of being compliant if nobody else is but you? I wonder if even `Opera` is compliant, or, for that matter, if all the RFCs it implements can be unambiguously interpreted in the first place. I don't think so, especially in the case of larger ones like `HTTP`.

If this sounds like HTTP bashing, let me just say this: HTTP is a great standard with concepts that revolutionized not only the internet. The way e.g. resources are specified (statelessness), or the way caching is done, has established good patterns that have trickled down into the implementations of many applications. And HTTP 2 could pick up where 1.1 left off. Let's just hope that *SPDY* won't be adopted 1 to 1. I hate to say it, but in this case it looks like Microsoft's *HTTP Speed+Mobility* is in many ways more *HTTP*-ey than Google's *PUSHy* (and insofar *unRESTy*) *SPDY*.

Comment: Citation needed for Japanese phones that don't handle UTF-8 but that have XHR to be able to process JSON (as opposed to e.g JSON-P).

Comment: @hsivonen That was a statement from a customer who uses our product. We had to modify our product for that reason, i.e. the customer had to pay for it, so I assume they are right. Unfortunately, I don't have more details like what model or OS etc.