# Printing encoded utf-8 webpage words with accents in python

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, beautifulsoup

I'm getting a webpage content (encoded as utf-8) by using BeautifulSoup4. The problem occurs when I try to print a word that has accents and python raises me the following error:

```
"UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 3-4: ordinal not in range(128)"
```

If I use .encode('utf-8') I don't get error anymore but also don't get the word correctly written (it gives me something with !@% within the characters with accents).

Is there a simple usage of any functions that gives me the chance to print the word correctly with all its accents?

Code:

```
def foo(soup):
    children = soup.find('div', {'id': 'test'}).find_all('p')
    for child in children:
      print child.name, child.string
    return '---'
```

The raised error occurs on the `child.string`

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Please provide the code. But before that, try to convert the string using `unicode(s)`.

Comment: Code added to the question. @evanbas I also tried using unicode(s) but it didn't work.

Comment: What you are telling us is that your code works fine but your terminal (or your Python, or these two together) are not configured for Unicode output. Encoding as UTF-8 will basically do what you describe but that is completely correct behavior, but you are viewing the output incorrectly. I'll try to find a suitable duplicate; there should be hundreds on this site alone.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting to UTF-8 (again)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13067748/converting-to-utf-8-again)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this on the top of the file if you want to do a testing

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Here is an attempt to fix the error.

```
print child.name, child.string.decode('utf-8')
```

Basically you should use decode instead of encode.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Just corrected from "decode" to "encode" and that works perfectly.