# How to search for a specific unicode string when web scraping?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, non-ascii-characters

I recently got interested in web scraping on Python and did it on some simple examples, but I don't know how to handle other languages that don't follow the ASCII codes. For example, searching for a specific string in the HTML file or using those strings to be written in a file.

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import requests
import bs4
website = 'http://book.iranseda.ir'
book_url = 'http://book.iranseda.ir/DetailsAlbum/?VALID=TRUE&g=209103'

soup1 = bs4.BeautifulSoup(requests.get(book_url).text, 'lxml')
match1 = soup1.find_all('a', class_='download-mp3')
for m in match1:
    m = m['href'].replace('q=10', 'q=9')
    url = urljoin(website, m)
    print(url)
    print()
```

Looking at this website under `book_url`, each row has different text, but the text is in the Persian language.
Let say I need the last row to be considered.
The text is "صدای کل کتاب"
How can I search for this string in `<li>`, `<div>`, and `<a>` tags?

Comment: what are you expecting to return?

Comment: where in your code are you attempting this match on the persian string?

Comment: The code is working using the specific encoding as Jack mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the encoding from `requests` to UTF-8. It looks like the `requests` module was not using the decoding you wanted. As mentioned in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13067748/converting-to-utf-8-again), you can tell requests what encoding to expect.

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import requests
import bs4
website = 'http://book.iranseda.ir'
book_url = 'http://book.iranseda.ir/DetailsAlbum/?VALID=TRUE&g=209103'

req = requests.get(book_url)
req.encoding = 'UTF-8'
soup1 = bs4.BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml')
match1 = soup1.find_all('a', class_='download-mp3')
for m in match1:
    m = m['href'].replace('q=10', 'q=9')
    url = urljoin(website, m)
    print(url)
    print()
```

The only change here is

```
req = requests.get(book_url)
req.encoding = 'UTF-8'
soup1 = bs4.BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml')
```